# Class: Add self as property using the constructor

Tags: javascript

I would like to get a javascript-class that maps children of itself to `children`.

This is what I got so far:

```
export default class Item {

    constructor (id, name, children = []) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.children = children.map((child)=>{
            return new Item(child.id, child.name, child.children)
        });
    }

    test(){
        console.log("Test");
    }

    //...
}
```

If I now call this:

```
let children = [
    {id: 1, name: 'foo'},
    {id: 2, name: 'bar'},
    {id: 3, name: 'foobar', children: [
        {id: 4, name: 'foo'},
        {id: 5, name: 'bar'},
    ]},
];

let newItem = new Item (item.id, item.name, item.children)
```

I thought I would get a recursive mapping like this:

```
[
  Item: { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
  Item: { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
  Item: { id: 3, name: 'foo', children: [ Item: { id: 4, name: 'foo'}, Item: { id: 5, name: 'bar'}] },
]
```

In this case I should be able to call `test()` on any child.

```
newItem.children.forEach((child){ child.test(); });
```

But this throws

> _vm.child.test is not a function

Comment: Your vairable is `children` but you pass `item.children`. Could that be the issue ? because your code is ok. Also you are missing the arrow in your `forEach`. `(child)=>{`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly. I suspect it is in the way you're creating the objects.

Here, I simply provided an `id`, string as `name` and send in your `children` object. Your code, unmodified creates what you expect:

```js
class Item {

  constructor(id, name, children = []) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.children = children.map((child) => {
      return new Item(child.id, child.name, child.children)
    });
  }

  test() {
    console.log("Test");
  }

  //...
}

  let children = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'foo'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'bar'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'foobar',
      children: [{
          id: 4,
          name: 'foo'
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: 'bar'
        },
      ]
    },
  ];

let newItem = new Item(1, 'item', children)

console.log(newItem)
```